# Did protests in front of a foreign embassy ever succeed in achieving their goal?

Tags: protests, embassy

It is very common for protesters to express their dissent against a certain country's action by protesting in front of its embassy. [For example](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/world/protesters-rally-outside-russias-embassy-in-london-over-ukraine-invasion-9163716.html):

> Hundreds of British-based Ukrainians gathered outside the Russian Embassy in London today to protest against the build-up of troops in the Crimea region.
>
> The demonstrators chanted and held banners demanding "Hands off Ukraine".
>
> Many of them waved placards accusing president Vladimir Putin of being the "Russian aggressor" and they sang: "Putin is a murderer" and "stop the occupation".

But did those kind of protests ever achieve their goal? And if not, why do people even bother holding them in the first place?

Comment: You can get a spot in the Guinness book of world records for longest protest: the Wednesday protest by “comfort women” started in 1992, and was recognised as a record in 2002. It’s still ongoing in 2017, and probably will keep on going until they die of old age. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_demonstration

Comment: @AndrewGrimm but did it ever achieve anything?

Comment: it’s increased awareness of others to the issue.

Comment: Are you looking for a case in which an embassy protest was the primary driver of the protest's success? Embassy protests are usually derivative of much larger domestic protests.

Comment: @HHuang yes looking for examples where protests abroad made a measurable difference.

Answer (score 14):

Yes and No, **it depends what you mean** by achieving "their goal".

If you mean were the eventual aims of the protestors reached, most certainly yes. Protests [against the Vietnam war](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/march/17/newsid_2818000/2818967.stm), [ending apartheid in South Africa](https://nvdatabase.swarthmore.edu/content/us-activists-and-politicians-campaign-south-african-embassy-end-apartheid-1984-1985), and [independence for Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Sunday_(1972)#The_perspectives_and_analyses_on_the_day).

If you mean by the fact that a government immediately changed its position following an attempt to lobby its embassy abroad, then no I could not find any examples.

The aim of protesting an embassy is not necessarily to immediately change the foreign governments position (although undoubtedly many protestors would be happy for this to happen) but to **pressure your domestic government** into exerting pressure on this foreign government to change its policy. Or to **show your support for your domestic government** against a foreign governments pressure.

Comment: ... and getting publicity for your cause.

Comment: @SJuan76 Sounds like a truism - pretty much any public action or announcement is going to get you publicity. Unless you mean that publicity (as opposed to putting pressure) is the *main* goal of such protests, in which case I disagree.